# Inconsistent behaviour of authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application. I have a controller called `AjaxController`. There is a method `SaveComment` which is not decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute. The controller itself is not attributed with the above class as well. Basically the code is as follows

```
public class AjaxController : BaseController {
    public ActionResult SaveComment(CommentViewModel viewModel) {
        // stuff
    }
    // stuff
}

public abstract class BaseController : Controller {
    // some comment stuff
}
```

And this is  the `Web.config` setup

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Login" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

But when I request it from the browser, it redirects me to the login page.
What can be the reason of a such behavior?

**EDIT**

I don't override the `OnActionExecuted` and `OnActionExecuting` and methods do something with authentication pipeline either.

**EDIT**

A few more details: I have two more controllers `HomeController` and `LoginController` which are working perfect without authorization. Also I have another controller that forces authorization `MyController`, and the class itself decoraded with `Authorize`, and when I tried to decorate some action with `AllowAnonymous`, the attribute was ignored and it redirected to the login page.

Comment: @oybek..are you having [AllowAnnoymous] tag for login?

Comment: Are you sure that none of your routes are messed up and is forwarding the request to the controller that requires authorization?

Comment: @Mathew Yes, totally sure about that. It is working when the user is authorized.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please try this:**

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Nope, this didn't help.